# Undefined reference to extern int stm32

Tags: c, microcontroller, extern, undefined-reference, stm32

I'm using Atrollic Studio(problem also exists in Eclipse).

.h file

```
 extern int i2cInitIO(uint channel, uint hz);
 extern int i2cIO(uint device, byte *put, uint putlen, byte *get, uint getlen);
```

.c file

```
#include "tollosI2C.h"
int i2cGetReg(uint device, byte reg, byte *get) {
  // write one byte address then read 1 byte data

  return i2cIO(device, &reg, 1, get, 1);
  } // i2cGetReg
```

I have a problem: undefined reference to `i2cIO'.This project is need to be compiled by ARM tool chain.
StM32F103VET6 - high density devices.I'm use ST-Link.

UPD: my .h file - http://pastebin.com/52ftBxR9

and c. file - http://pastebin.com/CcjpVZUP

Compiler invocation command - "gcc"  without braces.

Compiler invocation arguments - "-E -P -v -dD ${plugin_state_location}/specs.c" without braces.

Comment: Platform? Linker command line? Linker settings?

Comment: did you provide a definition for i2cIO(...) somwhere? Or have you possibly forgotten to link against the containing library?

Comment: @wsevendays: where is `i2cIO` defined?

Comment: That's a declaration, not a definition. Where's the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your environment is called Atollic (spelling mistake), but from the name of the header file I conclude you are using the Tollos supervisor from Mike Cowlishaw.
Secondly, your compilation options may not be correct, since the `-E` option for GCC results in only preprocessed output being generated, the error you report is a linker error, however.

Without more information, I would assume you're missing a library containing the `i2cIO` implementation, probably a missing option for the linker command line.

Since you seem to be using a processor variant not directly supported by Tollos, I suppose you want to port Tollos for your processor. Check your makefile cq. Atollic project setup to include the correct libraries. And if appropriate, replace the `-E` option with `-c`.